# How should I repair a 2-1/4" notch in the bottom of a 2x8 floor joist?

Tags: flooring, code-compliance, joists, load-bearing, beam

I have a floor joist that is notched about 7 inches away from the bottom plate. The joist is a 2x8 (7 1/4) The hole is about 2.25 inches so I added a sister joist and the hole in that is probably 1.8 inches. First is this to code? If it’s not to code does adding the sister beam bring it up to code? And if not that what should I do to bring it up to code? Below is an image [image]

Comment: Code doesn't generally allow edge notches in joists. That edge is in _tension_ and is critical to the joist's role. What's the joist span?

Comment: On what does that floor joist bear?  Does it rest on the white concrete wall on the right, and the (partially) framed 1x4 wall on the left?

Comment: There are steel joist repair brackets.  They come with a lot of caveats and engineering information, but you might find that one is suitable here.  
 For example: https://joistrepair.com/collections/featured-products

Comment: sistered the full length but with the same notch?

Comment: Not an official answer, but I'd be inclined to screw a flat steel strap 2" wide around 2' long, under the whole lot, as the beam is under tension, and that would stop any spread underneath. Use a good half a dozen beefy screws. Pity whoever fitted the pipe couldn't have made the vertical parts longer.

Comment: @Tim I had the exact same thought, but I have doubt that it would meet code (which is the crux of the question).

Comment: There are code compliant joist repair straps, but generally, it would take an engineer to determine which one is applicable, then provide a signed/stamped document stating that it's sufficient. Without that, an insurance company may choose to not pay out if they find an approved fix to a non-code compliant notch like this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will take a licensed structural engineer to _properly_ design a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb for comparing strength is the joist strength is equivalent to the square of the inverse.

So if you have 7.25 this is equal to 52.56.  Now you've notched it 2.25 so you are at 5 and this would be 25.  You've sistered with the same notch so now you have 2x25=50 which is approximately equal to the 52.56 you originally had.

This assumes you've sistered the entire joist.

Your notch isn't terrible since it isn't anywhere near the middle span.  I'd be happy with your repair.

Comment: The primary question is about code. I'd also be fine with this fix, but your answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: If he sistered with the same notch then no.   code is full joists 16" oc.   if you notch then you'd need to meet the rules around notching with are 1 1/2" for 2x10 and 1 1/4 for 2x8.  the only thing that brings that up to code is getting an engineer to sign off or re-running the pipe through a hole and not a notch.

Comment: Or rerunning the pipe _under_ a new unnotched/undrilled joist.